# Если поле PRIMARY KEY, то NOT NULL не нужен?

Tags: mysql

Есть поле, являющееся первичным ключом. Это поле не должно содержать «нулевых» значений.

Есть ли необходимость в `NOT NULL`, или достаточно только `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: писать где? при создании таблицы? надо. пример `id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, к Вам новый вопрос. Вы говорите, что обязательно надо, другие,что не надо. В интернете почитал информацию. Там сказано, что вообще поле **PK** уже имеет **constrait** и **NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY **- "масло маслянное". В инных источниках сказанно, что для некоторых случаев это нужно. Так когда следует писать **NOT NULL** и **PRIMARY KEY**?

Comment: `В интернете почитал информацию`......`В инных источниках сказанно,` - лучше пишите эти самые источники. Я лично не понял что вы написали. Возможно что-то вырванное из контекста. .......................поле PK уже NOT NULL если в каком-нибудь редакторе создавать таблицу: там при указании, что колонка PK -  автоматом поставится галочка и что она NOT NULL. Есть такое

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а если создание таблици консольное, то писать отдельно NOT NULL?

Comment: что значит отдельно? какая разница консольное или нет..... вы пишите либо `CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,.......` либо `CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
Id int NOT NULL, ........еще столбцы, 
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)` ......... то есть тот столбец, которым вы посчитаете будет первичный ключ - пишите как not null ............... http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp → A primary key column **cannot** contain NULL values.

Comment: все понял, это я и спрашивал: писать **id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY / id INT NOT NULL ... PRIMARY KEY (id)** или же просто **id INT  PRIMARY KEY / id INT  ... PRIMARY KEY (id)**. Теперь я правильно изъяснился?

Comment: да) ну надеюсь что я тоже))

Comment: благодарю за внимание)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

У **уникальных** полей есть одна забавная особенность. Уникальность определяется равенством. Но `NULL` не равен `NULL`! Поэтому значения `NULL` можно добавлять в столбец с проверкой на уникальность в любом количестве строк!

А **первичный ключ должен уникально идентифицировать каждую строку по равенству значения этого ключа**. Потому значение `NULL` для первичного ключа **не имеет смысла**. При сравнении равенством он просто *никогда* не совпадёт *ни с какой* строкой.

Это распространяется на **все** SQL-совместимые базы данных.
Но [процитирую определение первичного ключа с dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_primary_key):

> A set of columns—and by implication, the index based on this set of columns—that can uniquely identify every row in a table. As such, it must be a unique index that does not contain any `NULL` values.

> Набор столбцов и индекс по этому набору столбцов, способный однозначно идентифицироать каждую строку в таблице. Это уникальный индекс, не содержащий значений `NULL`.

**Так что да, `PRIMARY KEY` требует, чтобы его столбцы были `NOT NULL`.**

И в зависимости от того, каким синтаксисом определяется первичный ключ, указание `NOT NULL` может быть обязательным или необязательным. **В MySQL (по всей видимости) обязательно всегда.**

Синтаксис определения первичного ключа я встречал трёх видов:

- Прямо при определении типа колонки, добавив `PRIMARY KEY` к её типу:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE things ( id integer PRIMARY KEY )
  ```

  - Указание `NOT NULL` *может быть* необязательным. Но в MySQL, судя по примерам (документация не особо помогла), **обязательно**. В PostgreSQL же нет: там считается, что `PRIMARY KEY` в типе столбца включает в себя `NOT NULL`.
- При определении первичного ключа в составе определения таблицы (но не её :столбцов)

  ```
  CREATE TABLE things ( id integer NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id) )
  ```

  - `NOT NULL` обязательно, иначе упоминание колонки в `PRIMARY KEY` будет конфликтовать с уже объявленным.
- При определении первичного ключа на уже созданной таблице отдельно.

  - `NOT NULL` обязательно, т. к. таблица уже определена.

Comment: а что именно означает фраза «но не наоборот»?

Comment: Возможно вопрос и глупый, после Вашего объяснения, но я его задам. Так в случае,если у меня **id INT** является **PRIMARY KEY**, мне следует писать **NOT NULL**? В одних источниках пишут, как и Вы, что **PRIMARY KEY** уже имеет **constraint**, а другие говорят - **NOT NULL + PRIMARY KEY**, ибо это необходимо в некоторых ситуация. Что это за ситуациии и, честно говоря, не понимаю, если **PRIMARY KEY** определяеться по дефолту как **NOT NULL**, чуть ли не во всех примерах это определяют явно - значит,если на определить это ограничение явно, то могут возникнуть определенные проблемы?

Comment: и соглашуть с alexander barakin, а что именно "но не наоборот"? не **NULL**???????

Comment: Дополнил ответ. "Но не наоборот" осталось от старой редакции, где мне показалось неочевидным, что указание `NOT NULL` не зачисляет колонку в первичный ключ автоматически, что было бы по меньшей мере странно.

Comment: @D-side, огромное спасибо)